# update a table by using for loop with parameters in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table with some columns like [image: this.]

now I want to use a for loop to set

```
out_0 = 0, 
out_1 = 1, 
out_2 = 2, 
out_3 = 3, 
out_4 = 4
```

so I update it with such code as

```
string sql = "update exchange_out set @column = @id where member_id = 6;";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connet);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@column", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);

int n = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters["@column"].Value = "out_" + i;
    cmd.Parameters["@gid"].Value = i;

    n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                
    MessageBox.Show("" + n);
}
```

but it didn't write any data into the table while **it literally did five times of updating, because the messagebox returns "1" five times.**

finally I solve this by

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        sql = string.Format("update exchange_out set {0} = {1} where member_id = 6", "out_" + i, i);
}
```

but I'm still wondering why it didn't work by adding parameters?

any respond will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Hint: what are the names of the parameters in your SQL? And what are the names of the parameters you've set in your loop?

Comment: (As a second note, I'm not at all sure that you can specify field names using parameters in SQL server...)

Comment: I'm fairly certain query parameters are just for values, not for table/column/etc. names.

Comment: correted, sorry about the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm still wondering why it didn't work by adding parameters?

Identifiers such as table and column names cannot be parameterized in this way, only data. Your attempt effectively runs a query like this:

```
update exchange_out set 'out_1' = 1 where member_id = 6;
```

It's the same in any programming language:

```
var data1 = "hello";
var whichData = "1";

Console.WriteLine(data+whichData); //it doesn't compile; you cannot programmatically build a variable name `data1` in this way
```

The way you found is reasonably the only way but you should still parameterize the *data*:

```
using var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connet);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    sql = string.Format("update exchange_out set out_{0} = @data where member_id = @id", i);
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.Parameters["@data"].Value = ...
    cmd.Parameters["@id].Value = 6;

    ...
```

You could also start with an SQL stub like `"UPDATE t SET "` and repeatedly concatenate on identifiers and parameters:

```
using var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connet);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
var sql = "UPDATE exchange_out SET ";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    sql += string.Format("out_{0} = @data{0},", i);
    cmd.Parameters["@data"+i].Value = ...
}
sql = sql.TrimEnd(',');
sql +=  " where member_id = @id";
cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = 6;
cmd.CommandText = sql;

    ...
```

This does the update in one operation, running a query like `UPDATE t SET out_1 = @data1, out_2 = @data2 ...`

These are safe from SQL injection because your code controls the entire SQL; there isn't any capacity for a user to provide `'; DROP TABLE Students;--` as the `{0}` going into the identifier *in this case* but take care that you don't arrange for it to be possible (don't let the user provide identifier text)..

Your non-parameter attempt is also safe from SQL injection *in this case* by virtue of inserting intergers that you control, rather than strings you don't, but be careful you don't universally apply the technique and one day include user-suppied strings. If you do find yourself in that suitable you should use something like a whitelist of user input - any string identifier provided by the user that isn't whitelisted should not be put in the SQL